# weblogic 12c: stopping nodemanager without killing managed server

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, nodemanager

We are using weblogic 12c, and we have a managed server named `app1` on our application server.  We would like to stop and restart nodemanager to rotate the ssl certificate that we use for nodemanager.  However, whenever we use the `$DOMAIN_HOME/bin/stopNodeManager.sh` or call `stopNodeManager()` from wlst, it also kills `app1` along with nodemanager.

1. Is there some configuration setting that is causing the `app1` managed server to go down and startup with nodemanager?  If so, what is it?
2. is there some other way to take down nodemanager without the `app1` managed server also being shutdown?